# Strugling to scrape titles with scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am currently trying to scrape a title via Scrapy's shell. https://cineb.art/movies is the website,
the title is located in :

```
   <h3 class="film-name">
```

When i type response.css("film-name").get() i get nothing in return

> > > fetch('https://cineb.art/movies')
> > > 2022-11-01 12:17:24 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET [https://cineb.art/movies>](https://cineb.art/movies%3E) (referer: None)>>> response.css('film-title').get()
> > > response.css('film-name').get()

this is my log. Help me out! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

there is an "a" tag under "h3" tag and you need to get text

```py
response.css("h3.film-name a::text").get()
```